# performSegueWithIdentifier does not instantiate UIViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller

I have a class of UINavigationController (and linked to the storyboard "mainNavCont") containing:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"init"); 
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSLog(@"View Appeared");
    UINavigationController *selfNavController = [self navigationController];
    [selfNavController performSegueWithIdentifier:@"rootToPortSeg" sender:self];
}
```

There is a segue in the storyboard with the identifier "rootToPortSeg", type is "push", that links to a UIViewController called "portViewCont". In that class there is the following:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"I am the port");
}
```

Everything compiles fine and I get no errors in Xcode. But the portViewCont UIViewController never loads or displays or anything. I am still new to iOS and for the life of me I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. I get "init" and "View Appeared" in the console but not "I am the port", Thanks SO!

[image]

Comment: You say that the view controller isn't instantiated, but you're getting a log in the init method and viewDidAppear?  What class is the above code in -- I'm not clear on the structure of your app.

Comment: the UINavigationController does instantiate, its the UIViewController after the segue that does not.

Comment: @rdelmar I have updated my question to include the storyboard.

Comment: @Fresheyeball Rather than trying to perform the segue (which it looks like you can't do if you don't have a root controller set up for the navigation controller), you can, though, instantiate the view controller and then push to it. See my updated answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After thinking some more about this problem, I think the best way to go would be to use a custom container controller with a portraitController and landscapeController as its children.

In the following code, I instantiate the 2 child controllers in the container controller's init method, and have strong properties pointing to them so, that when switching back and forth, you'll be accessing the same instances. I set up the initial view controller in the method that checks for the device orientation at start-up, and then do the switching of the controllers in a call back to the UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification.  Finally, the actual switching with animation is done using the transitionFromViewController:toViewController:duration:options:animations:completion: method.

```
#import "ContainerController.h"
#import "LandscapeController.h"
#import "PortraitController.h"

@implementation ContainerController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    if (self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil]) {
        self.portCont = [[PortraitController alloc]initWithNibName:@"PortraitController" bundle:nil];
        self.landCont = [[LandscapeController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LandscapeController" bundle:nil];
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(checkLaunchOrientation) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
    }
    return self;
}


-(void)checkLaunchOrientation {
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] !=0) {

        if (UIDevice.currentDevice.orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait | UIDevice.currentDevice.orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown){
            if ([self.currentController class] != [self.portCont class] ) {
                self.currentController = self.portCont;
                [self addChildViewController:self.portCont];
                [self.view addSubview:self.portCont.view];
            }
        }else if (UIDevice.currentDevice.orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft | UIDevice.currentDevice.orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight){
            if ([self.currentController class] != [self.landCont class] ) {
                self.currentController = self.landCont;
                [self addChildViewController:self.landCont];
                [self.view addSubview:self.landCont.view];
            }
        }
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(orientationChanged:) name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];
    }else{
        [self checkLaunchOrientation];
    }
}


-(void)orientationChanged:(NSNotification *) aNote {
    if (UIDevice.currentDevice.orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait | UIDevice.currentDevice.orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown){
        if ([self.currentController class] != [self.portCont class] ) {
            [self addChildViewController:self.portCont];
            [self moveToNewController:self.portCont];
        }
    }else if (UIDevice.currentDevice.orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft | UIDevice.currentDevice.orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight){
        if ([self.currentController class] != [self.landCont class] ) {
            [self addChildViewController:self.landCont];
            [self moveToNewController:self.landCont];
        }
    }
}


-(void)moveToNewController:(id) newController {
    [self.currentController willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
    [self transitionFromViewController:self.currentController toViewController:newController duration:.6 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft animations:^{}
        completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [self.currentController removeFromParentViewController];
        [newController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
        self.currentController = newController;
    }];
}


-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I liked where rdelmar was going on his analysis, but as you saw, it looks like you can't perform a push segue from the navigation controller itself (which makes sense). But, it looks like you can `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier`, then you can `pushViewController` to that from the navigation controller fine. Thus, if the subclassed `UINavigationController` has a `viewDidLoad` like:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // this is the storyboard identifier for the portrait view controller

    UIViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"portrait"];

    // now you can push to it

    [self pushViewController:controller animated:NO];
}
```

Then, the portrait view is loaded, you see its `@"I am the port"`, you see the controls you added in Interface Builder for that view, etc.

---

**Update:**

I have to confess that while the above technique works, I wonder if that's the best way. Specifically, looking at your storyboard, I'm inferring that your goal is to have one view controller for portrait and another for landscape. If that's what you want to do, you can just use the technique that Apple lays out in their *View Controller Programming Guide* in the [Creating an Alternate Landscape Interface](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH7-SW14) section.

Maybe you can describe why you're using a navigation controller to do this, when it wasn't really designed to handle that. It's really more geared towards handling the pushing and popping of view controllers, not for choosing between different view controllers. I think you can make it work, but I wonder if the technique described in the *View Controller Programming Guide* might be more appropriate. But maybe you have some functional requirement that is not immediately apparent from your storyboard.

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Storyboard (<UIStoryboard: 0x83a32e0>) doesn't contain a view controller with identifier 'portViewCont''

Comment: @Fresheyeball You must not have defined the Storyboard ID for the destination view controller in Interface Builder. Note (a) it's case sensitive; and (b) there are a bunch of different attributes in Interface Builder (e.g. label, restoration id, title, etc.), but you want to fill in the Storyboard ID for the view controller in question. Let us know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your setup correctly, the code you posted is in your MainNavCont controller.  If that's so, I don't understand what you're doing with this line:

```
UINavigationController *selfNavController = [self navigationController];
```

The class your code is in *is* the navigation controller, you should just be using self in the performSegue: method:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"rootToPortSeg" sender:self];
```

Comment: I tried that, but it gave me an error. the navigationController attribute of self must be declared.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. Is that exactly what the error message says? Can you post the whole error message?

Comment: 2012-10-05 21:28:51.848 Orientation switcher delgated from navigation controller[27473:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Could not find a navigation controller for segue 'rootToPortSeg'. Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController.'

Comment: OK -- I think your problem is the way your storyboard is set up. I don't know how you got that structure, but normally a navigation controller has a "relationship" to its rootViewController. Where is your root view controller?

Comment: @rdelmar I'm sorry I am very new to this. What do you mean rootViewController? I thought the mainNavCont controller was the root?

Comment: No, it's not. You need to tell me what you're trying to do -- if the code you wrote actually worked, it would immediately go to the portViewCont. Is that what you want? Will you go forward or back from there to another controller?

Comment: @Rob said nav bar was there, I hid it.

Comment: What I want is to use the segue to portViewCont from mainNavCont when mainNavCont "viewDidAppear", I want it to be immediate.

Comment: But do you have some content in mainNavCont?  Will you want to be able to go back to mainNavCont from portViewCont at some point?

Comment: yes, but there will never be any content in mainNavCont, its just a switcher.

Comment: Well, I don't understand that. Why would you want to go back to a controller that's just a switcher and has no content? Will you then segue to another controller you haven't made yet?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17634/discussion-between-fresheyeball-and-rdelmar)